# Регулярные выражения Python вернуть true если слово не начинается на цифру, и в слове встречается больше 5 цифр подряд

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Регулярные выражения Python вернуть false если слово не начинается на цифру, и в слове встречается больше 5 цифр подряд

примеры слов:
19181920flupandemic
covid19
blackdeath
coronavirus
italy
covid1920
pandemic
sarscov2
2009flupandemic
2020coronaviruspandemicinitaly

Из списка должны остаться:
covid19
blackdeath
coronavirus
italy
pandemic
sarscov2

Нашла (^\d\w.*$)
Но как применить не знаю

```
text = ['19181920flupandemic','covid19','blackdeath','coronavirus','italy','covid1920','pandemic','sarscov2','2009flupandemic','2020coronaviruspandemicinitaly']
text2 = []
for i in range(len(text)):

    if len(str(text[i])) <= 15:#слово короче 15 символов


        if str(text[i]) and #здесь хочу вставить условия регулярных выражений
             text2.append(str(text[i]))
```

Comment: Вернуть true или false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import re

text = ['19181920flupandemic','covid19','blackdeath','coronavirus','italy','covid1920','pandemic','sarscov2','2009flupandemic','2020coronaviruspandemicinitaly']

r = re.findall(r'^\D+\d{0,5}', text[1]) #Вместо text[1] подставляете любую строку

print(r)
```

Comment: Это ж неправильно?

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант (за образец взят предыдущий ответ от [Alioshca Z](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/369912/alioshca-z))

```
text = ['19181920flupandemic','covid19','blackdeath','coronavirus','italy','covid1920','pandemic','sarscov2','2009flupandemic','2020coronaviruspandemicinitaly']

text2 = []

for items in text:
    if (re.findall(r'^\D', items)) and not (re.findall(r'\d{6,}', items)):
        text2.append(items)

print(text2)
```

Результат:
['covid19', 'blackdeath', 'coronavirus', 'italy', 'covid1920', 'pandemic', 'sarscov2']

Примечание: в представленном вами входящем списке нет строки, которая отвечает обоим условиям из заголовка (т.е. не начинается с цифры и содержит больше 5 цифр подряд). В вашем примере выходных данных цифр как раз должно быть от 0 до 5.

Вторая часть регулярного выражения может выглядеть как-то так – not (re.findall(r'\d{6,}', items)

т.е. не 6 и более цифр подряд.

Предложенный ранее вариант пропускает строки, где число цифр подряд больше 6 (тестовый пример 'sarscov23456789').

```
r = re.findall(r'^\D+\d{0,5}', "sarscov23456789")
print(r)
```

вывод ['sarscov23456']

Примите это во внимание, если к вам в список попадают не только указанные ранее строки.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде вот такое должно подойти:

```
^(?!(?!\d).*\d{5})
```

Если надо всё-таки true, то внешние отрицание удалить.